# How do i authenticate facebook login with IOS using node.js + Passport

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, passport-facebook

Currently I want to authenticate my user using facebook on IOS platform. I want to use node.js as the custom authentication, so that i could make it more flexible. My theory right now is to use node.js and passport-facebook via token, but my questions right now

1) Do i need to use Facebook ios sdk together with node.js /passport? or simply just serve it via node.js/passport https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios

2) If the user already installed facebook on his iphone, how do i access the token?

This is my first time on creating an iphone app + facebook login, any advice would be highly appreciated. It is a project that I'm working on right now

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can authenticate the user on the phone with the iOS SDK. That way the user will get the native "login with Facebook" flow and your application will get hold of the Facebook token. Then you take this token, pass it to your node backend (together with the email address of the user), and you can use passport/NodeJS to verify that the token belongs to the email address. If so, the user is authenticated and you can store the token together with the email (and other user related custom data) in you node node application for use later on and to fetch an existing user in your node application when they log in again.
For the rest of the authentication you can use something like JWT (Json Web Token), https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt, to secure your backend and to know which user sent the request.